# How to replace the characters in fixed positions in PHP?

Tags: php, string

I want to replace with the `4~8` characters of a string with `*`,how to do it?

```
HelloWorld

=>

Hell****ld
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use

```
substr_replace()
```

like

```
substr_replace($string, '****', 4 , 4);
```

read more :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$var="HelloWorld";
$pattern="/oWor/";
$replace="****";
echo preg_replace($pattern,$replace,$var);
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$string = 'HelloWorld';

for ($i = 4; $i <= 8; ++$i) {
    $string[$i] = '*';
}
```

But there is many, many more ways to do that.

Answer (score -1):

```
$var="HelloWorld";
$result=substr_replace($var, '****', 4,4 ) . "<br />\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to use [substr_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php).

```
$str = substr_replace("HelloWorld","****",3,-2);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$str="HelloWorld";
print preg_replace("/^(....)....(.*)/","\\1****\\2",$str);
```

Comment: This pattern is working too hard.  Consider https://stackoverflow.com/a/59046173/2943403

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$e=str_split("HelloWorld");
$e[3]="*";
$e[4]="*";
$e[5]="*";
echo implode($e);
?>
```

User can change only the characters that he need.

Comment: There is no need to slit and implode.  See Crozin's similar technique.  Your post is low value on Stackoverflow because there is no plain English explanation of what your snippet does or how it works.

Comment: In my example, user can change only the characters that he need. 
For example 2 and 4. Please, remove the dislike

Comment: If you need to change 10 different characters (2,3,5,8,14....), you will use 10 time the same function, or this example?

Comment: Regardless of how many characters you need to change, there is no benefit to calling `str_split()` or `implode()` ...again, see Crozin's answer.