# Replace or insert characters into a string based on a numeric position in the string

Tags: php, string, replace, substring

Is there a function in PHP that takes in a string, a number (`i`), and a character (`x`), then replaces the character at position (`i`) with (`x`)?

If not, can somebody help me in implementing a function which can replace or insert a substring?

Comment: Note that `substr_replace()` can do this (and other types of replacing / inserting), but is not necessary if you are only replacing a single character.

Comment: No shortage of signposts for this canonical [How to replace the characters in fixed positions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2513859/2943403) and [Replace a specific character at a specific position with some other character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23141464/2943403) and [Replace character's position in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12339642/2943403) and [PHP - using substr_replace to replace an occurrence of a word with a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47082872/2943403)

Comment: and [PHP to replace 2 character at nth position in an string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42199424/2943403) and [Fastest way to remove character from string at specific index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43771871/2943403) and [Replace characters in between a string using substr_replace in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28144249/2943403) and [How to Replace a Word With Another Word Using Str_replace Function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38526786/2943403)

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
$str    = 'bar';
$str[1] = 'A';
echo $str; // prints bAr
```

or you could use the library function `substr_replace` as:

```
$str = substr_replace($str,$char,$pos,1);
```

Comment: Ref: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr

Comment: does this work as expected with unicode strings where the characters are all multibyte?

Comment: @Matthew What could I do if I want to remove the `a` to get final string `br`?

Comment: @sємsєм Perhaps you want `$str = substr_replace($str, 'a', '')`

Comment: @Matthew No I mean removing character by its position in the string.

Comment: @sємsєм First off, I meant `str_replace('a', '', $str)` in my prior comment. If you want to remove a character by its position in the string, just use `''` as the replacement string. `$str = substr_replace($str,'',$pos,1);` If you have further questions, you should really start your own new SO question.

Comment: Note that above will not work for an empty string. `$str = ""; $str[0]='A'` after that `$str` becomes an array... Go figure ;-).

Answer (score 15):

I amazed why no one remember about [substr_replace()](http://www.php.net/substr_replace)

```
substr_replace($str, $x, $i, 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

[Codaddict is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994300/php-function-to-replace-a-ith-position-character/3994306#3994306), but if you wanted a function, you could try...

```
function updateChar($str, $char, $offset) {

   if ( ! isset($str[$offset])) {
       return FALSE;
   }

   $str[$offset] = $char;

   return $str;

}
```

[It works!](http://codepad.org/pcdnZQjC)

Answer (score 1):

```
function replace_char($string, $position, $newchar) {
  if(strlen($string) <= $position) {
    return $string;
  }
  $string[$position] = $newchar;
  return $string;
}
```

It's safe to treat strings as arrays in PHP, as long as you don't try to change chars after the end of the string. See the manual [on strings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr):

Comment: ...and all of characters before and at the designated position are all single-byte characters.  Accessing characters by their offset is less intuitive and prone to mistakes when multibyte strings are involved.

Answer (score 0):

```
implode(':', str_split('1300', 2));
```

returns:

> 13:00

Also very nice for some credit card numbers like Visa:

```
implode(' ', str_split('4900000000000000', 4));
```

returns:

> 4900 0000 0000 0000

[str_split — Convert a string to an array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

Comment: This doesn't look like what he's asking for.  For example, if he wanted to add a colon in the 11th position of "I will need tomatoes, peppers and onions", your suggestion would not produce the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

`substr_replace()` is capable of replacing *n* number of <s>characters</s> bytes starting from *x* offset (positive or negative) in a given string with another string and has an optional parameter for limiting the number of <s>characters</s> bytes consumed before injecting the replacement string.

Multibyte strings are fine to use, but the offset and length parameters will count each byte of the multibyte characters.

Examples: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VNYbk))

```
echo substr_replace('stack',  'i',    2,  1);  // stick
echo substr_replace('stack',  'u',   -3,  1);  // stuck
echo substr_replace('stack',  'o',    1,  2);  // sock
echo substr_replace('stack',  'ge',  -2,  2);  // stage
echo substr_replace('stack',  'bri',  0,  3);  // brick
echo substr_replace('stack',  'hre',  1, -1);  // shrek
echo substr_replace('stack',  'hre', -4, -1);  // shrek
echo substr_replace('stack',  'y',    3,  0);  // stayck   ...consume no bytes
echo substr_replace('stack',  'y',    3);      // stay     ...consume remaining bytes
echo substr_replace('voilà',  'ci',  -2);      // voilci   ...à has two bytes
echo substr_replace('voilà',  'ci',  -3);      // voici    ...à has two bytes
echo substr_replace('sûreté', '',     4);      // sûr      ...û has two bytes
```