# Replace character's position in a string

Tags: php

In PHP, how can you replace the second and third character of a string with an `X` so `string` would become `sXXing`?

The string's length would be fixed at six characters.

Thanks

Comment: Dupe: [PHP function to replace a (i)th-position character](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994300/php-function-to-replace-a-ith-position-character?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks, saw this and used `substr_replace('string', 'XX', 1,2);`

Comment: @Michael your commented solution can be safely removed now since the advice is represented in an answer.  (Please don't comment solutions)

Comment: @waraker you can mark your question as resolved by awarding the green tick to the answer that you found most helpful.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on what you are doing.

In most cases, you will use :

```
$string = "string";
$string[1] = "X";
$string[2] = "X";
```

This will sets $string to "sXXing", as well as

```
 substr_replace('string', 'XX', 1, 2);
```

But if you want a prefect way to do such a cut, you should be aware of encodings.

If your $string is 我很喜欢重庆, your output will be "�XX很喜欢" instead of "我XX欢重庆".

A "perfect" way to avoid encoding problems is to use the [PHP MultiByte String extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php).

And a custom mb_substr_replace because it has not been already implemented :

```
function mb_substr_replace($output, $replace, $posOpen, $posClose) {
    return mb_substr($output, 0, $posOpen) . $replace . mb_substr($output, $posClose + 1);
}
```

Then, code :

```
echo mb_substr_replace('我很喜欢重庆', 'XX', 1, 2);
```

will show you 我XX欢重庆.

Comment: +1 for pointing out encoding issues. In this use case it won't be problematic.

Comment: you should keep with standard of substr having 'length', not 'end position'

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
<?php
$str = "string";
$str[1] = $str[2] = "X";
echo $str;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

For replacing, use function

```
$str    = 'bar';
$str[1] = 'A';
echo $str; // prints bAr
```

or you could use the library function substr_replace as:

```
$str = substr_replace($str,$char,$pos,1);
```

similarly for 3rd position

Answer (score 1):

```
function mb_substr_replace($string, $replacement, $start, $length=0)
{
    return mb_substr($string, 0, $start) . $replacement . mb_substr($string, $start+$length);
}
```

same as above, but standardized to be more like **substr_replace** (*-substr-* functions usually take *length*, not end position)