# Replace a specific character at a specific position with some other character

Tags: php

How do I replace a specific character at a specific position with some other character?

I know the position of the character to be replaced.

```
$filtBuild = "BB10-1_X-4759-566549";
```

Comment: Maybe you could google this: "replace a specific character at a specific position with some other character php"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `substr_replace()`

```
$string = "Hello";
$char = "a";
$pos = 1;
$str = substr_replace($string,$char,$pos,1);

echo $str;  // Hallo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr_replace()`

```
substr_replace ( $filtBuild , $replacement , $start , $length )
```