# Exploding a string multiple times then Imploding it

Tags: php, explode, implode

I have been trying to explode a string twice then imploding it.
Here's what I mean by exploding it twice.
So I have a string

```
:0,0,1,0,0:0,0,0,0,0:
```

I want to edit the third zero and change it to one. 
How do I do that?
I"ve tried exploding the `:` then exploding the `,` but then Idk how to implode it.

I have tried this code but I can't implode the :

```
$exploding = ':0,0,0,1,0,0:0,0,0,0,0:';
        $explode = explode(':', $exploding);
        $explodes = explode(',', $explode[1]);
        $explodes[$part] = $type;
        $explodes = implode(',', $explodes);
```

Comment: You have to show what you have tried

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994300/php-function-to-replace-a-ith-position-character

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added another answer specifically answering the question asked, but might I suggest a different approach that is more extensible to more complex problems?  PHP allows you to access strings as arrays, with the index being the zero-based position of a character in the string.

**Code:**

```
$string = ':sd0,2[wsdsjds0sdfs0ksdjse00df0';
echo $string.'<br />';

$zeroCounter = 0;

for ($i=0;$i<strlen($string);$i++) {


    if ($string[$i] === '0') {

        $zeroCounter += 1;

        if ($zeroCounter === 3) {
            $string[$i] = '1';
            break;
        }

    }

}

echo $string;
```

**Output:**

```
:sd0,2[wsdsjds0sdfs**0**ksdjse00df0
:sd0,2[wsdsjds0sdfs**1**ksdjse00df0
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Explode on :
$array = explode(':', $string);
// Now explode each on ,
foreach ($array as &$substring) {
    $substring = explode(',', $substring);
}
// Change third 0 to 1
$array[1][3] = '1';
// Now implode on ,
foreach ($array as &$substring) {
    $substring = implode(',', $substring);
}
// Now implode on :
$new_string = implode(':', $array);
```

The reference variables in the `foreach` loops allow you to update the array elements in place.

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/pEmpwx)

A simpler version that's like your attemp would be:

```
$exploding = ':0,0,0,1,0,0:0,0,0,0,0:';
$explode = explode(':', $exploding);
$explodes = explode(',', $explode[1]);
$explodes[$part] = $type;
$explode[1] = implode(',', $explodes);
$exploding = implode(':', $explode);
```

[DEMO](http://ideone.com/KQIGQK)

Comment: instead of making it 1, it made it 01 and it removed the comma after it.

Answer (score 0):

$part and $type are undefined in this example, but this code should change the third 0 to a 1 for this specific string:

```
$exploding = ':0,0,0,1,0,0:0,0,0,0,0:';
    $explode = explode(':', $exploding);
    $explodes = explode(',', $explode[1]);
    $explodes[2] = '1';
    $explodes = implode(',', $explodes);
```

This seems oddly specific though, so I'm not sure if you're just trying to figure out how explode works or if you want something that will work with different strings as well.

Check my other solution for a better way of solving these problems.

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct but incomplete, this works for me:

```
$part = 3;
$type = 1;
$exploding = ':0,0,1,0,0,0:0,0,0,0,0:';
$explode = explode(':', $exploding);
$explode[1] = explode(',', $explode[1]);
$explode[1][$part] = $type;
$explode[1] = implode(',', $explode[1]);
$explode = implode(':', $explode);
print $exploding;
print "<br/>";
print $explode;
```

output:

```
:0,0,1,0,0,0:0,0,0,0,0:
:0,0,1,1,0,0:0,0,0,0,0:
```