# Replace characters in between a string using substr_replace in PHP

Tags: php

I want to replace the month number of a string of date in **mm-dd-yy** format.

```
<?php

    $db_currentDate = '2015-01-26';
    $month = '03';
        echo substr_replace($db_currentDate,$month, 5,6);

?>
```

But this output only **2015-03** , I want this output to be **2015-03-26**.
Can anyone help me with this? Thanks

Comment: `string: "03" (length=2)`

Answer (score 3):

Just change this line:

```
echo substr_replace($db_currentDate, $month, 5, 6);
```

to this:

```
echo substr_replace($db_currentDate, $month, 5, 2);
                                              //^ See here
```

As a reference to `substr_replace()` from the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

You can see this quote:

> length
>   If given and is positive, it represents the length of the portion of string which is to be replaced

Answer (score 0):

or you can try this always works

```
<?php

    $db_currentDate = '2015-01-26';
    $month = '03';
    $db_newDate_array = explode("-",$db_currentDate);
    $db_newDate = $db_newDate_array[0]."-".$month."-".$db_newDate_array[2];
    echo $db_newDate;

?>
```

let me know if that helps :)

Comment: That is an extremely long way round of solving this issue

Answer (score -1):

regular expression version!

```
echo preg_replace('/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/i', '${1}-03-$3', $db_currentDate);
```