# strreplace PHP function for utf-8 string

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, preg-replace

I want to replace character at specific index of string.

```
preg_replace('/('.$txt.')/u', $replacement, $str,1);
```

but it's not taking index, so not working for me.
How can I do this easily?

Comment: Have a look at [*PHP function to replace a (i)th-position character* SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3994300/php-function-to-replace-a-ith-position-character). Does that solution work for you?

Comment: @stribizhev substr_replace not working for utf-8

Comment: Also, please have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/p5MDzP) - is it something like you are looking for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To manipulate Unicode strings, you need to use appropriate string functions. Here, you can use [`mb_substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-substr.php):

> Performs a **multi-byte** safe `substr()` operation based on number of characters. Position is counted from the beginning of **`str`**. First character's position is `0`. Second character position is `1`, and so on.

Sample PHP code:

```
$str = "Вася";
$replacement = "н";
$start = 3;
echo mb_substr($str,0,$start-1,"utf8") .
                    $replacement . 
                    mb_substr($str,$start,mb_strlen($str),"utf8");
```

This will change `Вася` into `Ваня` as the 3rd symbl will get "replaced" with the `$replacement`.

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/p5MDzP)

Answer (score -2):

With php, if you do

> $string[1] = $replacement;

It will replace the character within the String.