# How to Replace a Word With Another Word Using Str_replace Function

Tags: php

i have a string and i want to replace  at particular position that sting with another word i have different string every time suppose that

```
string1=123456789
string2=012345678
string3=987654324
```

Now i want to replace 9 th character every time with 'M'  with php str_replce means after str replace string will change in this format

```
string1=12345678M
string2=01234567M
string3=98765432M
```

Good Suggesstion needed fo it

Comment: Is this classwork?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the library function substr_replace

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php

```
 substr_replace($your_string,"M",8,1);
```

Τhird parameter is the offset position in which the replacing will begin.8 in your case since you need the 9th character to be replaced.

Fourth parameter represents the length of the portion of string which is to be replaced.In your case you just need 1 character.

Comment: what is mean of 8,1 as u define in function

Comment: @user2909776, George gave you a link to the official docs so you can look it up

Comment: I updated the answer but if  you want more details on how the function works you can look up the docs too :)