# PHP to replace 2 character at nth position in an string

Tags: php, str-replace

I am developing bilingual website in codeignitor and i have created language files. All works fine except when switching the language i want to replace the language abbraviation in the url at 31th and 32th position starting at 0.

English Url :

> $url=http://localhost/abc/index.php/**en**/news/title/new-version-of-goldendict-with-dzongkha

Dzongkha Url :

> $url=http://localhost/abc/index.php/**dz**/news/title/new-version-of-goldendict-with-dzongkha

i just want php to change **en** to **dz**

i tried

> $url=http://localhost/abc/index.php/**en**/news/title/new-version-of-goldendict-with-dzongkha
>
> $lang_id='dz';
>
> $old_lang=substr($url, 31, 2);
>
> $newurl = str_replace($old_lang,$lang_id,$url );

However above codes changes dz to en but also replaces 45 and 46 character. This is what happens after conversion.

> $url=http://localhost/abc/index.php/**dz**/news/title/**dz**w-version-of-goldendict-with-dzongkha

Any one who has an idea whats happening

Comment: good old `$newurl = str_replace('/en/','/dz/',$url);` might be enough here?

Comment: Why would you need to replace a language string? You should build the urls correctly according to the current language. Including the title which seems to be fixed to one language now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this -

```
$url="http://localhost/abc/index.php/en/news/title/new-version-of-goldendict-with-dzongkha";

echo $str = substr_replace($url,'dz',31,2);
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: worked without a glitch, i see what u did there and too bad i assumed substr_replace works only with 5 parameter... thanks @Afshan

Answer (score 2):

Since you are implying that the country code is always at the 31th position in your string, you can use the [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-replace.php) function to limit the scope of your replacement.

```
$newurl = substr_replace($old_lang, $lang_id, $url, 31, 2);
```

Another option is to be more specific in your search string as proposed by Scuzzy in the comments : `$newurl = str_replace('/en/','/dz/',$url);`

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$url = "http://localhost/abc/index.php/en/news/title/new-version-of-goldendict-with-dzongkha";

function changeLanguage($url, $language)
{
    $new_url = "";
    $url_broken = explode("/", $url);
    foreach ($url_broken as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($value, ".php")!==false) {
            $lang_index = $key+1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isset($lang_index)) {
        $url_broken[$lang_index] = $language;
    }
    $new_url = implode("/", $url_broken);
    return $new_url;
}

$url = changeLanguage($url, "dz");
var_dump($url);
```

This method will help you to change the language on the basis of pattern not on the basis of position. And of course in this i have considered language will be after *.php/