# Fastest way to remove character from string at specific index?

Tags: php, arrays, string

I previous removed charactors from a string by using:

```
$str[$position] = '';
```

I need to do this several times and in a loop:

```
while ($condition == true)
{
     $str[$position++] = '';
     // My code
}
```

The code worked perfectly and was very efficient, however, it no longer works now that I've upgraded to PHP 7.1.4.

If I use:

```
while ($condition == true)
{
     $str[$position++] = ' ';
     // My code
}
```

It works, but I get unwanted spaces.

I could make this work using, `substr_replace`, however, that would be extremely inefficient. What's the fastest and most efficient way to solve the problem and why doesn't it work with PHP 7.1.4?

EDIT

I fixed the code that stopped working after upgrading PHP by using `substr_replace`. At first it would appear [tcPeng](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6631691/tcpeng) is correct in saying:

> if you assign a empty string to a string offset, a warning should be raised and the string shouldn't be modified

because that is the exact problem I was having. However, elsewhere in my code, I have:

```
while (trim($file[$i]) !== 'default:')
    $file[$i++] = '';
```

Surely, that code should no longer work either. The strange thing is, it does work. Why does it work, and is there any point in me changing the code to use `substr_replace`?

The only differences between the code I had to fix with `substr_replace` and the code that happens to still work, is the code I had to fix, the string was an element of an array and it was being output with `echo`. With the code that still works, I am saving it with `file_put_contents`.

Answer (score 2):

In php7.1, if you assign a empty string to a string offset, a warning should be raised and the string shouldn't be modified.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71572

So if you want to remove a specific index in a string, try this:

```
$a = 'hello';
$a = substr($a, 0, 1) . substr($a, 2, 5);
var_dump($a);    // string(4) "hllo"
```

or this may be more efficient:

```
$a = 'hello';
$a = substr_replace($a, '', 1, 1);
var_dump($a);    // string(4) "hllo"
```

in php5 or php7.0, if you use `$a[1] = ''`, the string `$a` is this:

```
$a = 'hello';
$a[1] = '';
var_dump($a);    // string(5) "h\000llo"
```

the index 1 of string `$a` is replaced with `\000`, the null value. It is not actually removed. So if you want to get `hllo`, index assignment is not a good option.

hope this helps...