# PHP - using substr_replace to replace an occurrence of a word with a string

Tags: php, str-replace

I am trying to replace three occurrences of the word "NOUN" with the contents of three different strings. I am new to PHP and would appreciate being pointed in the right direction!

Also worth noting, I don't *have* to use substr_replace, but to my knowledge, is it the best way to do it?

Below is what I have been trying, and it doesn't produce any changes when I echo $sentenceBx1's new contents:

```
$numAdjectSentence = substr_count($sentenceBx1, "ADJECTIVE");
$numVerbSentence = substr_count($sentenceBx1, "VERB");
$numNounSentence = substr_count($sentenceBx1, "NOUN");

substr_replace(string, replacement, start)
$nounPos1 = strpos($sentenceBx1, "NOUN");
substr_replace($sentenceBx1, $nounBx1, "test", $nounLength);

$nounPos2 = strpos($sentenceBx1, "NOUN");
substr_replace($sentenceBx1, $nounBx2, $nounPos2, $nounLength);

$nounPos3 = strpos($sentenceBx1, "NOUN");
substr_replace($sentenceBx1, $nounBx3, $nounPos3, $nounLength);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

substr_replace returns its result. So you need to use a structure like:

```
$result = substr_replace($sentenceBx1, $nounBx2, $nounPos2, $nounLength);
```

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

```
$sentenceBx1 = substr_replace($sentenceBx1, $nounBx1, $nounPos1, $nounLength);
```

### Explanation

Looking at the specification of [`substr_replace`](http://php.net/substr_replace), you can see that the description of substr_replace is:

```
mixed substr_replace ( mixed $string , mixed $replacement , mixed $start [, mixed $length ] )
```

This tells a lot of things. First is that it does not change any of the variables passed to it. The reason we can tell is because none of the parameters are [*passed by reference*](http://php.net/references.pass). You can always tell if a parameter is passed by reference by looking at the specification of the function and look for an *ampersand* (`&`) like this:

```
string &$string
```

In short, when you pass a variable to a function as a standard parameter, you only pass along a *copy* of the variable, meaning that the function you call cannot really change its content. (Actually, it is a bit more complicated than that, as PHP will only copy the value if needed, and internally use a reference if not needed, but you don't need to worry about that right now I presume.) But when you pass a variable by reference, you pass not a copy of the value, but a reference to its memory location. So when the function you are calling is trying to change the content of the parameter, it follows the reference and changes the content of the original variable you sent.

A minimal example would be as follows:

```
$lorem = 'ipsum';
function foo($lorem) { $lorem = 'dolor'; echo $lorem, PHP_EOL; }
function bar(&$lorem) { $lorem = 'tenet'; echo $lorem, PHP_EOL; }
echo $lorem, PHP_EOL;
foo($lorem);
echo $lorem, PHP_EOL;
bar($lorem);
echo $lorem, PHP_EOL;
```

It will print:

```
ipsum
dolor // (inside foo)
ipsum // after foo, your original variable remains unchanged
tenet // (inside bar)
tenet // after barm your original variable is updated
```

So, back to the specification of substr_replace, *how **do** you get* the resulting string?

> Return Values
>
> ---
>
> The result string is returned. If string is an array then array is returned.

So, you want to do

```
...
$sentenceBx1 = substr_replace($sentenceBx1, $nounBx1, $nounPos1, $nounLength);
...
$sentenceBx1 = substr_replace($sentenceBx1, $nounBx2, $nounPos2, $nounLength);
...
$sentenceBx1 = substr_replace($sentenceBx1, $nounBx3, $nounPos3, $nounLength);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing, however I assigned it a new variable ever time I used substr_replace. Not the most efficient way, but it makes for working through step by step easier.