# How to hide a particular post with "preg_replace" or shorter code?

Tags: php, string, replace, str-replace

How to hide a particular post with PHP "preg_replace" or shorter code?

I want to show the **first 5** and **last 5** digits **after `pub-`** of the specified text. The string always starts with `pub-` and there are always **16 numbers in the sequence**. Only the numbers change. I want to replace the middle 6 digits with asterisks.

```
$string = "pub-9752787982789258";

echo "pub-" . substr(explode("-", $string)[1], 0, 5) . '******' . substr(explode("-", $string)[1], 11, 5);
```

RESULT:

```
pub-97527******89258
```

Comment: So, the string must start with `pub-` and then has only digits, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  yes, true. It always starts with pub-. and there are 16 numbers in the sequel. Only numbers change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you need to hide the substring in the middle only in strings that match the specific format** you may use

```
preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!^)|^pub-\d{5}(?=\d*$))\K\d(?=\d{5})~', '*', $string)
```

See the [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/Wmkt7) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nUjBDh/2).

**Details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^pub-\d{5}(?=\d*$))` - end of the previous successful match or `pub-` at the start of the string and then 5 digits followed with any 0+ digits up to the end of the string and then
- `\K` - omits the text matched so far
- `\d` - matches any 1 digit
- `(?=\d{5})` - makes sure there are five digits on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try this kind of approach:

```
echo substr_replace($string, '******', 9, strlen($string) -14 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the string width be fixed, I might suggest avoiding regex here and instead just use the base string functions:

```
$string = "pub-1885335825402893";
$output = substr($string, 0, 9) . "******" . substr($string, 15, 5);
echo $output;

pub-18853******02893
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the input is strictly formatted and has a static length, there is no need for a regex call and this can be done with just one function call (making it easier to read and maintain and more efficient).

Count to the correct position in the, either from the front with a positive integer or from the back with a negative integer, then set the replacement length equal to the number of asterisks.

My `preg_replace()` call is the longest and least efficient technique.  It consumes and forgets the first 5 digits, then replaces the next 6 digits.

To make individual replacements, the final two techniques (regex with `\G` continue metacharacter or `for` loop) will do the job.  The regex will be even less efficient than the earlier regex.  The `for()` loop may be competitively fast, but I don't really see the benefit in making 6 separate replacements for your scenario.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/cSkXN))

```
$string = "pub-1885335825402893";
echo substr_replace($string, '******', -11, 6);

echo "\n---\n";

echo substr_replace($string, '******', -11, -5);

echo "\n---\n";

echo substr_replace($string, '******', 9, 6);

echo "\n---\n";

echo substr_replace($string, '******', 9, -5);

echo "\n---\n";

echo preg_replace('~\d{5}\K\d{6}~', '******', $string);

echo "\n---\n";

echo preg_replace('~(?:\G(?!^)|^pub-\d{5})\K\d(?=\d{5})~', '*', $string);

echo "\n---\n";

for ($offset = 9; $offset <= 14; ++$offset) {
    $string[$offset] = '*';
}

echo $string;
```

Output:

```
pub-18853******02893
---
pub-18853******02893
---
pub-18853******02893
---
pub-18853******02893
---
pub-18853******02893
---
pub-18853******02893
---
pub-18853******02893
```

Comment: Note that without a `(?=\d+$)` lookahead in the `^pub-\d{5}` part, `'~(?:\G(?!^)|^pub-\d{5})\K\d(?=\d{5})~'` makes little sense as it does not check the string format and is not that better than a non-regex approach. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58703168/3832970) contains the regex solution that actually does both validation and replacing if validation succeeds.

Comment: The OP states clearly that validation is not necessary since the input string is strictly formatted.  I respect what your snippet is doing, I just think it is not necessary for the task that is presented.